# Rails server fails to boot with mysql2 - Gems it requires, exists

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, windows64

This is me trying to use MySql on rails for the first time. This happens with using sqlite3 as well except it points to me do 'gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter`,the tells me there is no such gem named it.

I am using the lastest Ruby 2.0.
I am using the lastest Rails 3.2.13
I have the mysql2 (0.3.11) gem
I also have the activerecord-mysql2-adapter (0.0.3)

Yet... it is giving me the following message:

`C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:214:in 'block in replace_gem': Please install the mysql2 adapter: 'gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter' (mysql2 is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.) (LoadError)`

The bundler ran when I executed `rails new [project name]`

If it was mysql2 gem's error, this command successfully installs mysql2 on 64 bit Windows systems:`gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.11' -- '--with-mysql-lib="C:\MySQL\lib" --with-mysql-include="C:\MySQL\include"'`

Gemfile generated is using `gem 'mysql2'`ok, normal as I have been told.

Database.yml is as follows:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: shop_development
  pool: 5
  username: charlie
  password: *******
  host: localhost
```

And I have manually created a database called [projectname]_development.

```
C:\Users\Charlie\Documents\RailsProject\demo_app>rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.13 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integ
ration.rb:214:in `block in replace_gem': Please install the mysql2 adapter: `gem
 install activerecord-mysql2-adapter` (mysql2 is not part of the bundle. Add it
to Gemfile.) (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/act
ive_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/ac
tive_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/ac
tive_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/ac
tive_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/ac
tive_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/act
ive_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:50:in `resol
ve_hash_connection'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/act
ive_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:41:in `resol
ve_string_connection'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/act
ive_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:25:in `spec'

        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/act
ive_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:130:in `esta
blish_connection'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/act
ive_record/railtie.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/ac
tive_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/ac
tive_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/ac
tive_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/ac
tive_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/ac
tive_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/act
ive_record/base.rb:720:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/act
ive_record/railtie.rb:88:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/i
nitializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/i
nitializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/i
nitializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/i
nitializable.rb:54:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/i
nitializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/a
pplication.rb:136:in `initialize!'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/r
ailtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
        from C:/Users/Charlie/Documents/RailsProject/demo_app/config/environment
.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Users/Charlie/Documents/RailsProject/demo_app/config.ru:3:in `re
quire'
        from C:/Users/Charlie/Documents/RailsProject/demo_app/config.ru:3:in `bl
ock in <main>'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder
.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder
.rb:51:in `initialize'
        from C:/Users/Charlie/Documents/RailsProject/demo_app/config.ru:in `new'

        from C:/Users/Charlie/Documents/RailsProject/demo_app/config.ru:in `<mai
n>'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder
.rb:40:in `eval'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder
.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.
rb:200:in `app'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/c
ommands/server.rb:46:in `app'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.
rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.
rb:254:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/c
ommands/server.rb:70:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/c
ommands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/c
ommands.rb:50:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/c
ommands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for following things

- Does your `Gemfile` have the entry saying `gem 'mysql2'` ?
- What happens when you run `$ bundle update` command? any errors
- Can you try the following command to generate your app,

  `rails new demo_app -d mysql`

What error you get when you try the above app?

Comment: Gem fiels contains gem'mysql2', bundle update sucessful, created new demo_app project using mysql database... successful -> `cd demo_app` -> `rails s`-> then i get the following error. Also i want to note it says `Rails 3.2.13 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000` it should be 127.0.0.1:3000 or localhost:3000, how to i change that?

Comment: no, `0.0.0.0` means that its listening on all interfaces. so not a bug/error. just open `localhost:3000` in your browser & it should work

Comment: I have just posted the complete errors I get, please take a glance.